# Delete UITableView row issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm having a problem that I see a lot of people having... however none of the fixes are working for me. But I did notice something odd happening when I put NSLog commands in the code.

I have the standard delete method:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView commitEditingStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.recipes removeObjectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView endUpdates];

    }

}
```

recipes is the array that holds the data source.

Theoretically this should work just fine, but  I get the error:

```
invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (9) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (10), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted).
```

But I know where this is falling apart, when I add an NSLog into the numberOfRowsInSection, I see that the method is being called twice from the method above.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"THIS CALLED TWICE  %i",[recipes count] );
    return [recipes count];
}
```

Anyone know what else could cause the numberOfRowsInSection method to fire twice?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: removed tag 'xcode' http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing this,  I saw that I had the following:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}
```

Apparently, numberOfRowsInSection is called for each section... changing the code to:

```
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }
```

Fixed the issue.